# How to clear text in element by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Current I using jQuery `append()` method to add in text in html element.

The code fragment as below:

```
$(".email-address td:nth-child(1)").append("Hello");
```

How can I clear the text I append previously?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I found $("selector").empty() helps in solving my problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `$("selector").text("Hello")` instead